# Problem recovering backup files on Ubuntu 20

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I had to install Ubuntu from scratch due to some issues. But when I try to use backup files, I get this error:

```
Temp space has 61751296 available, backup needs approx 272629760.
```

Like the image below:
[{.png}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf62u.png)

The file I want to recover is less than 1 MB in size. Is a Python file. I see this message when I select it and press the restore button.
[Just a Python file with 50 lines of code{.png}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2jJs.png)
I used the default Ubuntu tool for backup

**Can anyone help me?**

Comment: The message seems pretty clear. You need 272629760 (units) of storage space, but you have just 61751296. You will need to move/delete some files in order to make space for the backup to be restored 

Comment: The file I want to recover is less than 1 MB in size. Is a Python file

Comment: Is the backup compressed? I'm not sure if this happens on Ubuntu, but I know that on Windows certain types of compressed archives require the entire archive to be extracted to view a single file